# No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, cdi

I'm trying to use CDI to inject a DAO into my ManagedBean

**ManagedBean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.timbrasil.network.dao.ColaboradorDao;
import br.com.timbrasil.network.modelo.Colaborador;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable{

    private Colaborador colaborador = new Colaborador();
    @Inject
    private ColaboradorDao dao;
```

**DAO**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.timbrasil.network.modelo.Colaborador;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@RequestScoped
public class ColaboradorDao implements Serializable{

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Colaborador buscaEmailESenha(Colaborador colaborador) {

        String jqpl = "select c from Colaborador c where c.email = :pEmail and c.senha = :cSenha";

        TypedQuery<Colaborador> query = this.manager.createQuery(jqpl, Colaborador.class);

        query.setParameter("pEmail", colaborador.getEmail());
        query.setParameter("pSenha", colaborador.getSenha());

        colaborador = query.getSingleResult();

        return colaborador;
    }
}
```

@Edit **My EntityManagerProducer:**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

@ApplicationScoped
public class JPAUtil {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("blueMonster");

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

**Beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

Eclipse shows me a warning at the @Inject, saying:

```
No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]
```

When i try to deploy it on WildFly:

```
15:04:41,551 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
15:04:41,551 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
15:04:41,551 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
15:04:41,676 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."network.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."network.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ColaboradorDao with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private br.com.timbrasil.network.mb.LoginBean.dao
  at br.com.timbrasil.network.mb.LoginBean.dao(LoginBean.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:372)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:293)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:531)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    ... 3 more
```

I do have the beans.xml on my project, just to allow CDI to work.

As ColaboradorDao is a class that belongs to me i don't have to use @Produces,right?
Then why the CDI doesn't what to create?
How can i correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually also please clarify the contents of your `beans.xml`, it's possible you need to add a scope to your dao class.

Since you're using annotated, you need to also provide a scope on your dao.  It's not being picked up because it's not annotated.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@RequestScoped
public class ColaboradorDao implements Serializable{
```

Then it should start working.

Comment: Edited the post with the EM producer i'm using and the beans.xml

Comment: Used #RequestScoped but still getting the message 
Unsatisfied dependencies for type ColaboradorDao with qualifiers #Default

Comment: Didn't thought the others would be helpful.
Done

Comment: I remove the project and the server is still showing the message...
Ill just download a new instance of WildFly

Comment: You may need to clear out the data, tmp folders if it's stuck.